# Returns None when I execute the play command twice quickly

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I'm currently making a discord.py music bot.

It works great, however i got a annoying bug >:( !

When I execute the play command twice quickly (which query youtube videos with yt_dlp), the first command crashes cause it returns `None` for some reasons but the second one works fine.

I don't fully understand asyncio and i think the problem might come from the `asyncio.to_thread()` ?

Code of the part that crashes :

```py
@classmethod
async def parse_from(cls, data):
    thread = asyncio.to_thread(ytdl.extract_info, data, download=False)
    result = await thread
    if 'entries' in result: #<= Crashes here because result is None
        try:
            data = result['entries'][0]
        except IndexError:
            raise commands.UserInputError('Aucune résultat n\'a été trouvé. Veuillez réessayer avec des termes de recherches différents.')
    filename = data['url']
    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_opts), data=data)
```

Traceback :

```
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
  File "D:\Bureau\CODE\Python\Bot-Discord\cogs\voice.py", line 51, in parse_from
    if 'entries' in data:
  File "D:\Bureau\CODE\Python\Bot-Discord\cogs\voice.py", line 158, in play
    song = await YT_Song.parse_from(song_query)
  File "D:\Bureau\CODE\Python\Bot-Discord\main.py", line 44, in on_message
    await bot.process_commands(message)
  File "D:\Bureau\CODE\Python\Bot-Discord\main.py", line 143, in <module>
    bot.run(config.private_token)
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: I suspect YouTube has a rate limiter that prevents rapid requests like this. Just check if `result` is `None`. `if result and 'entries' in result:`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Barmar I use a `while not result:` with `asyncio.sleep(1)` to query until i get what i want and it works perfectly now ! Thanks :)